# Handle bar Template in React

Tags: reactjs, handlebars.js

Currently we are migrating one application from jquery to react.
In existing app, handlebar is used for few html generation which further send to server for pdf generation . 
is it possible to re use the handlebar in the REact app. Basically we would like to  use the handlebar template and pouplate it with the Json from the backend in React app , is it possible, if so any pointers?

Comment: I want to port but I don''t want to port? - Handlebars and React are both View binding libraries, why you need both to interop is beyond me, if you are going to download json from the backend, just replace the handlebar binding with the react JS-in-HTML syntax. i.e. this `{{  }}` becomes this `{   }`

Comment: In your case, if I understand correctly, you have a json object in your backend, you send it to front end, then you use a handlebars template engine in the client to create an html string that you don't present it is to the user, just to send it back to backend for pdf generation... So my question is simple. Why this back n forth of data? Why don't you generate the html you want directly in the server side using a handlebars library of your server's language? I do that in C# using handlebars.net to generate email messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesnt have anything to do with React really. If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to running handlebar on the client side (in the browser). The answer is yes you can definitely import Handlebar in your react app and compile the template.

```
import Handlebars from "handlebars";

const hbr = `
<p>Hello, my name is {{name}}. I am from {{hometown}}. I have " +
"{{kids.length}} kids:</p>" +
"<ul>{{#kids}}<li>{{name}} is {{age}}</li>{{/kids}}</ul>
`;

const template = Handlebars.compile(hbr);
const htmlString = template(data);
```

Take a look at https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-http-c4565 as an example.

Comment: Thanks @Yongzhi. Additionally we dont want to view this in the browser, rather we just need this div (dangerouslySetInnerHTML) to construct as htmlstring which we further send to backend server for pdf generation . So in short, we get JSON from backend , use handlebar to render the content, and using Ref to get the div element . is there any betterway? any pointers

Comment: yes I render it to div just to demo it as an example. template(data) is returning the html string that you want. You can send the result of `template(data)` to your server

Comment: I would upvote this if the code was a working [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) embedded in the answer instead of an external link to CodeSandbox.

Comment: @JordanRunning I can include the snippet in the answer but I dont think stackoverflow can run snippets that have es modules

Comment: Personally I would just use [Handlebars.js from CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/handlebars.js) for demonstration, but it looks like the npm package works just fine, too, [using bundle.run](https://jsfiddle.net/jrunning/r79dL0eo/).